# Fazer o estado de um componente ser gerenciado por função

Tags: funções, typescript, classes, react-native

Bom dia pessoal, então minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Criei um componente Snackbar para o aplicativo em que trabalho, com a finalidade de substituir a ToastAndroid do React Native. Todavia, gostaria de saber se é possível e como fazer para gerenciar o estado e exibir a snackbar por meio de uma função global, tal qual fazemos ao chamar o ToastAndroid.

Como fazemos para chamar o ToastAndroid:

```
export const notification = (message: string, type?: MessageOptions["type"], duration?: number): void => {
  ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
    message,
    duration != undefined ? duration : ToastAndroid.LONG,
    ToastAndroid.CENTER,
  );
  return;
}
```

Existe essa função **notification** que pode ser chamada de qualquer lugar da aplicação e exibe o ToastAndroid na tela com a mensagem desejada.

Por sua vez, ao criar minha Snackbar, eu criei um componente que é chamado na raíz da aplicação, em App.tsx:

```
 render() {
        {...}
        return (
                {...}
                <ApplicationProvider mapping={mapping} theme={lightTheme}>
                    <Provider {...rootStore}>
                        <AppNav signedIn={signed} isConfigured={isConfigured} />
                        <TigerSnackbar />   <--- Aqui é chamado o componente
                    </Provider>
                </ApplicationProvider>
                {...}
        );
    }
```

Inicialmente eu criei o componente para ser chamado e ter seu estado gerenciado por Mobx, mas na arquitetura em que o código foi desenvolvido seria muito trabalhoso implementar essa solução. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de exibir meu Snackbar tal qual exibimos o ToastAndroid, por meio de uma função chamada em qualquer lugar da aplicação.

Grato desde já!

Comment: O ToastAndroid consegue ser executado dessa forma porque é uma chamada direta ao código nativo (Java), então ele não tem dependência com estado ou com a árvore de componentes do react. Acredito que seja mais simples utilizar uma lib já criada pela comunidade, ex: https://github.com/cooperka/react-native-snackbar ou react-native-paper

Comment: Fala grande Camilo, então eu tentei usar a primeira biblioteca, mas não funcionou bem no aplicativo e ela é muito rígida quanto alterações no código. Quanto ao paper, não estava disponível para a versão do RN que é utilizada no projeto